# What is the recommended practice for making Reporting Services available publicly?

Tags: web, ssrs

We have a publicly available web server (although IP restricted, usernames / passwords etc) that we need to be able to present reports through.  Our report server is located at a different site, so we need to be able to open ports for this.

Our initial consideration is to move the reportserver virtual directory **from port 80 to a different port - any recommendations?**

Also, as reporting services uses Windows authentication, what is the best way for the server to securely authenticate for this application only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We setup ours using SSL, and Windows Auth on the normal port 443 with port 80 redirecting to 443 before prompting for username and password.  Our external user base is pretty small so we just created them domain accounts.

Comment: Nice thing about this approach is if it's all domain users, or at least a very small number of users, you can use a certificate issued by your own CA, which is what we've done.